# Angular not loading images and content for some browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

I have created a portfolio web site for myself.  I used angular.js to display my 'about me' text content and my portfolio images and content.  It works perfectly on every computer in my house even after a hard reload of the site.  As of last week, I have been getting reports that it is not working on some computers.  I am having a hard time figuring out if this is a hosting issue or my issue, as people who report it not working did not have that problem a week ago and I have not updated it since.

The link is http://www.davidsandersdesigns.com/.  I feel like I am trouble-shooting blind because everything works fine on all my browsers and my machines even after my cache is emptied.  I am getting 401 errors sometimes.  And sometimes I do not.  Please help!

This is my json file.

```
{
"aboutMeContent": {
    "paragraph1":  "My name is David A. Sanders. I am a front-end web developer and graphic designer. I am fresh out of school and currently looking for a job where I may apply my skills, be challenged, and learn new things. I love design, creativity, web animation, ones/zeros, learning, french-pressed coffee, and my beautiful family…..did I mention my family? They are the reason I decided to pursue web development after all.",
    "paragraph2": "Aside from wrestling midgets (my kids), changing diapers, and day dreaming…..My top technical skills are HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, Velocity.js, jQuery, and web animation. My top design skills are Photoshop, Illustrator, and just simple pencil and paper."
},
"portTileContent": [{
    "name": "Charlottes 3rd Birthday",
    "type": "Graphic Design/Print",
    "skills": "Adobe Illustrator",
    "notes": "This is a birthday card I created for my beautiful daughter. Picture courtesy of Photographer Carly Miller.",
    "link":"",
    "image": "images/viewerImages/CharBdayCard3yr_viewerImage.png"
}, {
    "name": "domSpace Animation Project",
    "type": "Web Design/Animation",
    "skills": "HTML5, CSS3, Velocity.js, Object-Oriented Javascript, Illustrator",
    "notes": "An Animation project I created to practice my programming skills.",
    "link": "<strong>Link:</strong> Visit the link <a href='http://www.davidsandersdesigns.com/domspace/' target=_blank>here<\/a>",
    "image": "images/viewerImages/domSpaceImage_viewerImage.png"
}, {
    "name": "Something Stiched Something Sewn",
    "type": "Graphic Design/Print",
    "skills": "Adobe Illustrator",
    "notes": "A business card I created for Donna Pierce/Seamstress.",
    "link": "<strong>Link:</strong> Visit her facebook <a href='https://www.facebook.com/SomethingStichedSomethingSewn/?fref=ts' target=_blank>here<\/a>",
    "image": "images/viewerImages/somethingStiched_viewerImage.png"
}, {
    "name": "davidsandersdesigns.com build 2000",
    "type": "Web Design/My Portfolio Site",
    "skills": "HTML5, SASS, Bootstrap3, Angular.js, Velocity.js, Illustrator, Photoshop",
    "notes": "My Personal site to showcase my work.",
    "link": "<strong>Link:</strong> You are already here!",
    "image": "images/viewerImages/dsdesignsBuild2000_viewerImage.png"
}]
```

}

This is my controller file.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://www.davidsandersdesigns.com/angular.js/data.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.aboutMe = data.aboutMeContent;
    $scope.portTileSpecs = data.portTileContent;
});
```

});

This is my app file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: 401 is an unauthorized message. Sounds more like  server configuration issue or authorization code not shown. Do you have password protection on any directories?

Comment: Try clearing your cookies and you will likely be able to reproduce

Comment: I just checked to make sure, so no not that I am aware of.  Is it working on your machine?

Comment: I have multiple times.  And I have had friends try on their machines.  Some can and some cannot.  None have pulled the site up on their machines before.  Which boggles my mind.  It doesn't seem like a browser issue though because It has worked in chrome, IE, Firefox, and safari

Comment: works in firefox for me. try to isolate which browsers are getting errors

Comment: Occured to me it might be a `www` vs no `www` but seems fine either way

Comment: It is hard to do that.  My friend pulled it up yesterday on his iphone with safari and my other friend who was right by him could not pull it up on his android with chrome.  But it has working and not worked vice versa before.

Comment: Could the site of been compromized?

Comment: It is funny that you say that.  Another friend poised the same question.  It would not work on his machine until he appended the www. to the beginning and then it worked after with or without.  Why would that cause a problem?

Comment: One thing that seems to be a common issue at the moment.  It does not work on mobile phones especially androids using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate problem by opening site without `www` in chrome and got a CORS error.

This is because `www.site.com` and `site.com` are actually considered cross domain by browser when making ajax requests.

Change :

```
$http.get("http://www.davidsandersdesigns.com/angular.js/data.json")
```

To

```
$http.get("/angular.js/data.json")
```

OR:

Configure server to always redirect to `www` or not `www` when page loads.

People are very used to sites not needing `www` in url any more

Comment: Ok I just fixed that.  Did it fix the issue?

Comment: Yes..reloaded page (no www) in chrome and worked fine

Comment: Awesome! Its works with no problems now! How come it would work sometimes and not work sometimes?

Comment: Likely because some were using `www` and others weren't